# Rendering (CPU+GPU) crash almost every time

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a newly created .blend file (totally about 83 000 faces and 8 MB large) that crashes almost every time I Cycles-render with cpu+gpu. I have set it to 500 samples and 1920x1080@250% (i.e. not too memory-intensive. Usually I have alot higher settings when rendering with Cycles engine, without any crashing)

It is not crashing instantly, but after some time the white "Blender is not responding" screen appear and I need to kill the process.

Is it possible to check the file somehow, what makes it crash, if it is some setting or some objects that is corrupt?

I run Windows 10 pro, 32GB RAM, and Blender version 2.90. Using AMD radeon 7100 PRO graphics card.

Comment: it's probably a bug, your best bet would be to report it on the blender dev forms.

Comment: it is stranhhe because i have tried blender 2.8x and the same thing happens with this soecific file. so i suspect it is the file itself that is bugging.

Comment: I just tried to render after the coputer's wifi connection was dissabled, and it seems to work now, at least for once... Wonder if that is some clue ...